# Golang export HTML to PDF using go-wkhtmltopdf package

Tags: html, go, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I would like to export an HTML file to a PDF file in Golang. I am attempting to use go-wkhtmltopdf from
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf
I originally posted this to the Go forum:
https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/html-to-pdf-error/26811
We have made some progress, I no longer get an error after adding:

```
page.EnableLocalFileAccess.Set(true)
```

The current problem is that the stylesheet is not applied.

```
    file, err2 := os.Open("./templates/tutorial.html")
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err2)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    b1 := make([]byte, 1000)
    _, err2 = file.Read(b1)
    
    pdfGenerator, err := pdf.NewPDFGenerator()
    pdfGenerator.Dpi.Set(300)
    pdfGenerator.Orientation.Set(pdf.OrientationPortrait)
    pdfGenerator.Grayscale.Set(true)
    page := pdf.NewPageReader(bytes.NewReader(b1))

    page.EnableLocalFileAccess.Set(true)

    page.Allow.Set("./styles/")
    page.Allow.Set("./templates/")

    pdfGenerator.AddPage(page)

    err = EnsureBaseDir("./pdfFiles/test.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("EnsureBaseDir failed error: ", err)
    }

    err = pdfGenerator.Create()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("pdfGenerator.Create error: ", err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    err = pdfGenerator.WriteFile("./pdfFiles/test.pdf")
```

If I open this html file in the browser:

[image]

If I generate the PDF, it looks like this:

[image]

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: do you need it only with this tool, or anything is other tool is okay? If yes you can look at [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp), it is simpler, refer examples.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with this change:

```
    <base href="http://localhost">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```